# replace highcharts.js series data with new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to change the graph's data and it's x-axis to show the appropriate data from the button that a user clicks.

I know there are like functions like setData or addSeries, but it doesn't totally take away **ALL** the data from the original graph.

I want to completely **erase the old json data and insert the new json data** and also change the x-axis.

```
<script>

// OLD DATA
var json_nba_30_days = {{ nba_30_days_data | safe}};
var nba_30_days_x_axis = {{nba_30_days_x_axis | safe}}

// NEW DATA FOR UPDATE
var json_nba_months = {{ nba_months_data | safe}}
var nba_graph = Highcharts.chart('nba_graph', {

    title: {
        text: 'NBA Sentimental Analysis'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Reddit Fan Comments'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: nba_30_days_x_axis
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },


    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },


    series: json_nba_30_days // OLD DATA
});

var toggle_nba_months = $('#toggle_past_months_button');
toggle_nba_months.click(function(){

 // How do we update the graph above to new json data of json_nba_months?


});
```

Comment: you can use this http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData

Comment: add [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. So that we can sort out problems better

Comment: setData does set new data - see example http://jsfiddle.net/k0pkrkd1/. For updating an axis, use [Axis.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.update)